# How to use active class on bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having the following bootstrap navbar;

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>             
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i click on Menu 1, 3 & 4 i'm getting the desired color & background color using the following CSS;

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fbfbfb;
    background-color: #105b9c;
}
```

I want the same effects on Menu 2, when i choose one of the options (Option 1 or Option 2) from the dropdown. Currently i'm not getting it.

**UPDATED:**
[Fiddel link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthi8/aff0phbb/)

Comment: What happens, if you click on `Option 1`? Does your parent li get the class `active`?

Comment: No i'm not getting it.

Comment: You have no active class? Sure? A fiddle would be nice.

Comment: I have updated my question with fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Achieved it with following code;

```
$('nav li').on('click', function() {
    $('nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthi8/aff0phbb/7/)

Answer (score 0):

i have added a new rule .navbar-default .nav .dropdown.open > a to this existing CSS code.

CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .nav .dropdown.open > a
{
    color: #fbfbfb;
    background-color: #105b9c;
}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: When i choose any of the options, i want the active class to be applied on Menu 2 alone.